# stl vector assign vs insert

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I understand the semantics of the 2 operations , 
assign- erases before replacing with supplied values. 
insert - inserts values at specified location(allocates new memory if necessary).

Apart from this is there any reason to preffer one over the other?
Or to put it another way, is there any reason to use assign instead of insert.

Comment: Maybe you can rescue this question by asking this instead: "Assign vs insert **on empty STL vector**, any difference?"

Comment: Fair enough. Thats what i had in mind.

Comment: 12 years and still not revised. tsk tsk tsk

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you wish to invoke the semantics of `assign`, call assign - if you wish to invoke the semantics of `insert`, call insert. They aren't interchangeable.

As for calling them on an empty vector, the only difference is that you don't need to supply an iterator to insert at when you call `assign`. There may be a performance difference, but that's implementation specific and almost certainly negligable.

Answer (score 7):

`assign` and `insert` are only equivalent if the vector is empty to begin with. If the vector is already empty, then it's better to use `assign`, because `insert` would falsely hint to the reader that there are existing elements to be preserved.

Answer (score 5):

`assign()` will blow away anything that's already in the `vector`, then add the new elements.  `insert()` doesn't touch any elements already in the `vector`.

Other than that, if the `vector` you are modifying starts out empty, there is little difference.

Answer (score 1):

insert() will insert the elements at a particular position. It can be a single value, or multiple values using first and last iterators. Its like inserting more elements in front of a position.

assign() will just assign the values starting at beginning till end as per input agruments "InputIterator first and  InputIterator last ". This will remove all existing elements and instead populate the vector with new values as per range provided in its arguments.